# Common header for SplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

In my app, i have called splitViewController from my viewController(see code below). Now i need to have a common view on the top of the splitViewController to show my company label or such. How to add a common view on the top?

**Appdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
PopMenuViewController *menuVC = [[PopMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *menuNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuVC];

PopMenuDetailViewController *detailVC = [[PopMenuDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopMenuDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

menuVC.detailViewController = detailVC;

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[menuNavController, detailNavController];

     self.view.window.rootViewController = splitViewController; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use popular custom splitviewcontroller [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) by Matt Gemmell

It has all the layout of container setup by code which you can edit and just push the master and detail view lower and add a custom navigation bar at the top.